# Windows without window screen tracks

Tags: windows, screens

I have a window that needs a window screen to pass inspection. However, there are no tracks to slide the window screen into. What is recommended to make my own track or how can I place the screen?

[image: Window without window screen track]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a track to me, right where I'd expect it. I assume that this is a single-hung window (or acts as one with a screen installed), so the screen nests into the rabbet at the bottom of the upper (fixed) sash.

It's also possible that the small molding outboard of that location is removable, revealing a channel.

I can't imagine a modern residential window manufacturer foregoing provisions for insect screens.

[image]

Comment: And with a metal strip spring or two on the top of the screen.

Comment: I figured on one side, but maybe.

Comment: That might work if the top pane doesn't need to move...looks like the frame protrudes beyond that slot—but it's admittedly hard to tell from the photo angle.  Otherwise, perhaps some kind of screen with a flanged edge stuck into the next slot outward?