# How can I install screens on my double-hung windows?

Tags: windows, inspection, screens

I have a few rental properties that have windows with no window screen tracks (older wooden windows). Since they are rental properties, they will have to pass city inspection and most likely need screens. Any recommendation on what to use to make my own screen tracks or a better solution?

[image]

Comment: How is this not a rewording of your [earlier question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/296701/windows-without-window-screen-tracks), which you seem to have abandoned?

Comment: "Since they are rental properties, they will have to pass city inspection and most likely need screens." If you change nothing then they're grandfathered. - Recommendation is to replace the windows with ones that come with screens and are safety glass, not those freaking guillotines. - They're also too low to not have railings in front of them. You either do absolutely nothing, or *everything*.

Answer (score 1):

Many hardware stores (not blue or orange big box stores) will make custom size screens with frames that can be held in with [screen clips](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Barton-Kramer-Keller-Window-Screen-Clip-610/100175250?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-NA-MULTI-NA-PMAX-5762521-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D25H-025_004_BUILDER_HARD-NA-MULTI-NA-PMAX-5762521-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-BuildersHardware-71700000113523353--&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqpSwBhClARIsADlZ_TkRg6D9T85xBzRR-PApxWT3_T_9TTPpCFchOleOa5xENX7BuYdBsbkaAjidEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) on the outside.

This should work for you.